# Exporting mysql blob to xml then importing back dont get the same result in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I have some photos (not big, only 8kb) in mysql database (in my desktop). the field type is blob. actually i want to export the table to xml file then upload it to my database website. but it failed. I try to mimic it by exporting the table to xml file then importing it back to another table (the table's structure is same). I can do it but i don't get the same photos (only some encoding text). Here is some pieces of code:

Exporting the table to xml :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs,Encoding.ASCII);
ds.WriteXml(sw);  //write the xml from the dataset ds
```

Importing the xml to the dataset :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Open);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(fs);
```

Writing the dataset to another table :

```
   ...
   int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
   for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
   {  
       DataRow myDR = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
       ...
       byte[] myphoto = null;
       if(myDR["myphoto"].ToString().Length > 0)
       {
          myphoto = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myDR["myphoto"].ToString().ToCharArray());
       }
       //insert the data to the mysql table 
       ...
   }
   ...
```

Why i don't get the same photos in this another table?
sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this:

```
myphoto = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myDR["myphoto"].ToString().ToCharArray());
```

you are treating arbitrary binary data as **encoded** text; that **cannot** work. An `Encoding` is intended to turn text data *into* binary (of a given text format, i.e. the encoding), and to turn binary (of a given text format) back into text; it **cannot** treat arbitrary binary (that isn't in the expected format) as text. As a trivial example, ASCII only uses 7 bits of each octet; any octet with the MSB set is guaranteed to get corrupted at some point during this cycle.

If you want to represent binary data as a string, use base-64:

```
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(blob);
```

to convert back:

```
byte[] blob = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the answer. but i write the xml right from the dataset. how to apply the converter?

Comment: @satria without showing us what the xml looks like, how would we know?

Comment: I think you can look at the code above (Exporting the table to xml). I queried the table then send the data to the dataset. save them as xml by ds.WriteXml(sw). should i change the blob data (use the converter) in the dataset before write them to xml?

Comment: @satria I ran a quick test, and it is indeed base 64, so just `byte[] blob = Convert.FromBase64String((string)myDR["myphoto"]);`, assuming it is choosing to interpret `myphoto` as a string.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that solve my problem. actually my ultimate problem is uploading the xml to my website database. Do you know the same converter for php?

Comment: @satria no, but asking google for "base 64 php" tells me `$decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);`